# How can I fix this error "no matching function for call to ‘regex_replace..` "?

Tags: regex, c++11, compiler-errors

Given the following code:

```
std::string str;
str= std::regex_replace(str, std::regex("\r"), ""); // ERROR
```

I get the following error:
 `no matching function for call to ‘regex_replace(std::string&, std::regex, const char [1])’`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Quite naive question, but did you remember to import `<regex>`?

Comment: I writed `#include <regex>`

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/WMeTdG). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code not shown. Prepare a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
**I've had this problem before.**  
The following is the phenomenon that I test the same piece of code on different versions of G++.  
    
### 1.code
    
    
    
        #include<bits/stdc++.h>  
        using namespace std;  
        int main()   
        {  
            string str="abc111abc222";  
            regex reg("abc");  
            string solve=regex_replace(str,reg,"");  
            cout<<solve<<endl;  
            return 0;  
        }
    
     
    
### 2.Test
    
    
#### （1）The origin of the problem:g++ version 4.8.1
    
Testing environment：    
DevC++5.9.2     
g++ version 4.8.1 (tdm64-2)   
Whether to enable the c++11 option:    
Yes.Turn on`-std=c++11`
    
    
    Error:
    
    `[Error] no matching function for call to 'regex_replace(std::string&, std::regex&, const char [1])'`
    
    
    
#### （2）g++ 6.5.0
    
Testing environment：     
g++ 6.5.0  
Output：`111222`
    
    
#### （3）clang++11
    
Testing environment：  
In site of “nowcoder”  
C++(clang++11)  
Output：`111222`
    
    
### 3、The final solution:
    
    We could choose a later version of the G++ compiler.
```